How to get the size of a Blazor WASM PWA app
I have a large Blazor WASM PWA app that takes quite awhile to load following a re-publish to Azure. It's large due to the number of Blazor components and amount of c# code, not because of large/numerous content files. I am using AOT to speed execution of much of the c# code which has to run following many user interactions.  I am also using self-contained publish mode which adds to the size.
I'm curious to know just how big the app is when first loaded, but don't know how to find that out.  Once the re-published app has loaded, using the Network tab of Chrome's Dev Tools doesn't seem to help help because only the service-worker and my small content files load. And I'm not seeing anything in the Azure portal.  Is there a way to get what I'm looking for?

You could try go to development tools- console. For WASM all resources are in the wwwroot/wwwroot folder. Then run dir /s


